# Can a UK bank request to see unredacted statement from a payee?

Tags: united-kingdom

My father transferred some money accross to my bank account, which I no longer required and returned within a month.
TSB has frozen my account and told me this in a letter demanding I send payee's bank statment. Which I had to request from my father and emailed accross to tsb. The bank statement from my father had been redacted with only payments to me showing. The bank is demanding to see the full statemnt.
Are they within legal rights to demand someone else's full statement because they made a payment to me?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Transferring money back and forth quickly makes it look like you are laundering it or are part of a scam.**

Banks are legally required to flag suspicious transfers of money.  Transferring to then transferring back is suspicious.  I don't know if they can legally make you show them documentation, but they can and will involve the police if you do not.

Show them the documents.  Even if they don't have the legal authority to do it, the people they contact will.